# Limits to number of indexes using multind?

Tags: indexing

I am encountering errors building multiple indexes (10) using multind.  Are there some limits I run up against?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, there can be no more than 16 output streams open at any time and LaTeX already uses a few. I don't know if `morewrites` can help with `multind`, which is quite an old package. With `imakeidx` and the `splitindex` option you can have as many indices as you want, because only one write stream is used.

Comment: @egreg You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hardwired limit of 16 simultaneously open write streams and LaTeX already reserves three plus one each for `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Thus your limitation to ten indices is not surprising.

Possibly, `morewrites` can help with `multind` (I don't know and `multind` is really an old and unmaintained package).

However, with `imakeidx` and its `splitindex` option, you can have as many indices as you want. See the documentation with `texdoc imakeidx` or at [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf)

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of `imakeidx`)

Comment: See also my package robustindex at CTAN.